# sqlite and visualstudio

Tags: visual-studio, sqlite

How do I set an identity column for sqlite in visual studio? I am performing a new query and am trying to create a new table using script.

Answer (score 1):

Check out this [ADO.NET](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) provider for SQLite. It will provide you full Visual Studio integration, so you can easily use the XSD tool to create tables within your SQLite database and set the Identity column accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at [System.Data.SQLite](http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/) here. It offers your ability to talk to sqlite inside visual studio.